# Ape:: consensus tree and edge length lost , are there solutions for this?

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny, consensus, ape

I am Abraham. Please! Somebody can help me with the problem with ape:: consensus and the branch length lost?
I am having this problem too.
Regards

Comment: don't see to introduce yourself or beg for help. but instead clarify exactly what is it you are trying to do. what have you tried. where does it fail and what is the expectation. as it is, your question is unlikely to get answered. good luck

Answer (score 0):

A consensus tree describes ony which splits / edges are shared in the majority of the trees. There is no obvious way to assign edge length to such an tree, but Liam Revell descibes in this
[blog post](https://blog.phytools.org/2016/03/method-to-compute-consensus-edge.html)
several ways how this could be done.